# Can you still use single-attacks in dota 2 to avoid creeps?

Tags: dota-2

In DotA, you can avoid the aggro of the creeps by single-casing attack-based skills, e.g. Blades of Wisdom from Silencer or Frost Arrows from Drow. Can you still do that in DotA 2?

Comment: (As long as it's not autocast.)

Comment: To clarify what Decency is saying, creeps aggro only on attack-moving (right-clicking an enemy, or pressing A then left clicking them). When you have an ORB ability auto-toggled, you right-click enemies to use it, so it's considered a normal attack. However, when you use the ability once, it's considered an ability use, which does not draw aggro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for here is orb-walking. Just like in the original DotA, orb-walking in DotA 2 does not draw the aggro of creeps when you attack enemy heroes.

In the original DotA these kinds of skills were referred to as orb effects. In DotA 2, they are called Unique Attack Modifiers. It is called orb walking because people harass/kill enemy heroes with these skills by cancelling the full animation of the attack by moving, making it easier to land several hits in succession.

Like Decency mentions, you will draw the aggro of creeps if these skills are toggled to auto-cast. Note that not all unique attack modifiers are toggled skills (such as Anti-Mage's passive Mana Break) so you will draw aggro if you right click a hero near creeps in such cases.